# UILabels width issues when numberOfLines different of 1 (default) inside StackView

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have one `StackView` with horizontal axis with 2 `Labels` inside with content/hugging modification to create a left alignment (as can be seen in the UI result below).

When number of lines of both of them are 1 (which is the default value) it works as expected. ✅

However, **when** one or both of them changes the number of lines different to 1 **then** both labels get the same width although they have space enough to grow and/or shrink.

The **"workaround"** do AutoLayout with constraints inside a view, but still wondering why this is happening on the StackView.

See below the UI result for both scenarios:

1️⃣`numberOfLines` are **both** 1:

[image]

*(**Disclaimer:** ☝️ This is the result which I would like to have when number or lines are **not equal to 1**)*

2️⃣ One (or both) `numberOfLines` are **different** of 1 (default value):

[image]

✅ **Exptected result**

[image]

**SETUP:**

**StackView**

```
alignment: .fill
distribution: .fill
spacing: 8
contentMode: .scaleToFill
```

**Label 90C**

```
numberOfLines: 1 //or 0 or 2,3,etc. but then it has result 2 behaviour
lineBreak: .truncateTail
(basically default values)

huggingHorizontal: 750
huggingVertical: 250

compressionHorizontal: 750
compressionVertical: 250
```

**Label 2 u.**

```
numberOfLines: 1 //or 0 or 2,3,etc. but then it has result 2 behaviour
lineBreak: .truncateTail
(basically default values)

huggingHorizontal: 250
huggingVertical: 250

compressionHorizontal: 250
compressionVertical: 750
```

There is no constraint broken or anything that triggers me that something might be wrong. I would like to understand the cause of this behaviour this way I could find a solution, hopefully, for this problem, thank you so much.

If something is not clear, or there is some information missing please don't hesitate to ask for it.